# Issue with input from weighing scale controlling a stepper motor based valve

Tags: arduino-mega, stepper, serial-data

Hello and thanks for any help in advanced.

What changes do I need to make to my code to get rid of the issue of the valve opening up again at end of cycle in "Auto" function.

Hardware:

- Arduino Mega
- Bi-polar Stepper Motor connected to Valve.
- Weighing scale with TTL output.

Here is my code:

```
//Buttons
#include <mechButton.h> //Button Library
#define BTNa_PIN  10    //Button Pins
#define BTNb_PIN  6
mechButton aButton(BTNa_PIN);  // Set button to pin BTN_PIN.
mechButton bButton(BTNb_PIN);

//Stepper
#include <AccelStepper.h> //Stepper Library
#define dirPin 4          //Stepper Pins
#define stepPin 2
#define motorInterfaceType 1 //Interface set to driver
AccelStepper stepper = AccelStepper(motorInterfaceType, stepPin, dirPin);// Create a new instance 

//Analog inputs for setting Max and Min Distance
const int analogPin = A0;
const int analogPin2 =A1;

//Data types for Scale Reading for Optima OP900a
char inString[32];
float Input;
float Setpoint;
float fSetpoint;

//Setup
void setup() {
   
  Serial.begin(9600);           // Fire up our serial monitor for arduino and computer
  Serial3.begin(9600);          //Fire up Serial for Scale for input
  
  aButton.setCallback(Manual);    // Set up our callback. (Also calls hookup() for idling.)
  bButton.setCallback(Auto);
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(3500);      // Set the maximum speed and acceleration for stepper motor:
  stepper.setAcceleration(5000);
  
  Setpoint = 4.44;               // Auto parameters
  fSetpoint = (Setpoint*0.9);

}  
// Main Loop
void loop() {
   bool abuttonState;
   bool bButtonState;
   
   idle();                      // Let all the idlers have time to do their thing.
   abuttonState = aButton.trueFalse();    // Have a look at what the current button state is.
   bButtonState = bButton.trueFalse();
}
//Sub Functions
void Manual(void) {
    int maxOpen = analogRead(analogPin);
    maxOpen = map(maxOpen, 0, 1023, 0,100);

   Serial.print("Manual ");
   if (aButton.trueFalse()) {
      stepper.moveTo(0);
      stepper.runToPosition();
   } else {
      stepper.moveTo(maxOpen*40);
      stepper.runToPosition();
      
   }
}

void Auto(void) {
    int maxOpen = analogRead(analogPin);
    int minOpen = analogRead(analogPin2);
    maxOpen = map(maxOpen, 0, 1023, 0,100);
    minOpen = map(minOpen, 0, 1023, 0,100);
   
   while (Input < Setpoint){
     readScale();
     if (Input >= fSetpoint && Input < Setpoint){
     stepper.runToNewPosition((minOpen*10)+400);  //Blocking function research work around...
     Serial.print("Min");Serial.print(",");       //debugging
     Serial.println(Input);                       //debugging
     }
     else if (Input < fSetpoint) {
     stepper.runToNewPosition(maxOpen*40);         //Blocking function research work around...
     Serial.print("Max");Serial.print(",");       //debugging
     Serial.println(Input);                       //debugging
     }
     else{
     stepper.runToNewPosition(0);                 //Blocking function research work around...
     Serial.print("Close");Serial.print(",");     //debugging
     Serial.println(Input);                       //debugging
     }
     }
}

void readScale(void){
    byte inChar = Serial3.readBytesUntil('\n', inString, 18); //Scale reading for input
    float scaleInput = atof(&inString[7]);
    Input = scaleInput;
  }
```

I keep getting this strange behavior at the end of the "Auto" function where I am getting false 0.00 from the scale that causes the valve to open and close fully at the end.

```
Max,0.01
Max,0.01
Max,0.01
Max,0.00
Max,0.00
Max,0.00
Max,0.00
Max,0.35
Max,0.42
Max,0.51
Max,0.60
Max,0.66
Max,0.69
Max,0.75
Max,0.83
Max,0.88
Max,0.93
Max,1.00
Max,1.05
Max,1.11
Max,1.16
Max,1.21
Max,1.26
Max,1.32
Max,1.38
Max,1.43
Max,1.48
Max,1.53
Max,1.59
Max,1.64
Max,1.68
Max,1.74
Max,1.80
Max,1.84
Max,1.89
Max,1.94
Max,1.99
Max,2.04
Max,2.09
Max,2.14
Max,2.18
Max,2.23
Max,2.27
Max,2.32
Max,2.37
Max,2.41
Max,2.45
Max,2.50
Max,2.55
Max,2.59
Max,2.62
Max,2.68
Max,2.72
Max,2.76
Max,2.81
Max,2.85
Max,2.88
Max,2.93
Max,2.97
Max,3.00
Max,3.04
Max,3.08
Max,3.13
Max,3.17
Max,3.20
Max,3.23
Max,3.27
Max,3.31
Max,3.35
Max,3.39
Max,3.42
Max,3.46
Max,3.50
Max,3.52
Max,3.55
Max,3.60
Max,3.63
Max,3.66
Max,3.69
Max,3.73
Max,3.77
Max,3.80
Max,3.83
Max,3.87
Max,3.91
Max,3.94
Max,3.95
Max,3.98
Min,4.03
Min,4.06
Min,4.09
Min,4.13
Max,0.00
Max,0.00
Min,4.35
MZ��r��j
Min,4.36
Close,4.46
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here:

- `Serial3.readBytesUntil()` does not add a null character at the end of
  the string. You have to do it yourself if you want a properly
  terminated string.
- You are attempting to read a float starting at the eight byte of the
  string, even if you got less than eight bytes.
- `atof()` does not report errors. If it fails to parse a float, it just
  returns zero.

Just to see what may be going wrong, I suggest this version of
`readScale()` with verbose debug output:

```cpp
void readScale(void) {
    byte inChar = Serial3.readBytesUntil('\n', inString, 18);
    inString[inChar] = '\0';  // terminate the string
    const char *start = &inString[7];  // where the number is expected
    char *end;  // where strtod() found it ends
    float scaleInput = strtod(start, &end);
    Serial.print("Scale -> \"");
    Serial.print(inString);
    Serial.print("\", parsed \"");
    *end = '\0';  // terminate the string after the number
    Serial.print(start);
    Serial.print("\" as ");
    Serial.println(scaleInput);
    Input = scaleInput;
}
```

Comment: That helped a lot!  The first time I hit the auto button it works perfectly.  But the more times I hit it the error keeps coming back.  Do you think this has something to do with buffer overflow?  
`stepper.runToNewPosition` is blocking therefore it could be interrupting the `serial3.readBytesUntil`

Comment: Maybe. Or it could be the debug messages slowing down the code. Does the scale pause between messages? Does it help to set a higher baud rate on `Serial`?

Comment: the serial stalls for a good ~1s while moving to `maxOpen`.   I cranked the baud to 115200  no change.  I think using the accelstepper library always get me into trouble and in the end never use it.  Time to rewrite everything in millis().

Comment: `Scale -> "US,NT,+  US,NT,+  ", parsed "" as 0.00`
`Scale -> " 4.34lb", parsed "" as 0.00`
This is the serial error with your better parsing.

Comment: Do you think adding an `if(Serial.available() > 0)` would help?

Comment: If you don't want the Accelstepper library to block, then why don't you write your code non-blocking? The Accelstepper library is totally capable of that. Look the the examples which call the `run()` function regularily. That function is meant for non-blocking action

Comment: I know it is but the whole reason I was using the accelstepper library was for the ramping because the valve has significant static friction and ramping allows it to over come the issue and run at max speed without stalling.